# drupal 7 - Grouping by taxonomy terms

Tags: templates, drupal-7, view

I have a view called `products`, using `product content type` and are classified by the `product taxonomy terms`. I just want to show the `Title` and `Picture` from the node and group them by my tags.

**tags:**

- fruits
- dried canned goods
- dairy

Comment: So...what is your question/what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need to create a View.
In views you can make any filter for data and show in a new node, table, list, etc.